# Eigen Values for a standard form of tridiagonal Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In my attempt to find a formal solution to a problem in Chemical physics, I have come across a matrix of this form:

$\begin{bmatrix}
0      & V_{12}        & 0       & \cdots  & \cdots    &0 \\
V_{21} & 0             & V_{23}         & \cdots   & \cdots   &0 \\
0      & V_{32}       & 0        & \ddots   &  &\vdots \\
\vdots      & \vdots           & \ddots      & \ddots    &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots      & \vdots           &     & \ddots    &\ddots & V_{_{(N-1)N}} \\
0      & 0            & \cdots &\cdots &V_{N(N-1)} & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} $

where $V_{ij} = \cos(\theta_i - \theta_j)$

Comment: It does not look that restriction $V_{ij} = \cos(\theta_i - \theta_j)$ is of any use (assuming $\theta_i$ being arbitrary) comparing with $V_{ij}=V_{ji}$. Besides you forgot to formulate a question in the body of your text (from the title I guess you are interested in computing the eigenvalues of the matrix).

Comment: Is there any relation between $\theta$s?

Comment: No there is no explicit relation between $\theta's$